# Importance of Karl-Pearson Correlation

Tags: correlation, pearson-r

We know that, if $(X,Y)$ is jointly Gaussian, then uncorrelatedness of $X$ and $Y$ implies independence of $X$ and $Y$. We also know that Karl-Pearson correlation coefficient measures only linear relationship (if any) between $X$ and $Y$. This means that *if there is no linear relationship, then there is no relationship*. Is this the reason Karl-Pearson correlation coefficient considered important?

Comment: I would like to suggest you can answer this question simply by [searching our site for Pearson correlation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=pearson%20correlation) and viewing a few of the most popular posts.

Comment: $\perp (X,Y) \implies R(X,Y) = 0$ but the converse is not true. What do you mean by "relationship"?

Comment: "jointly" Gaussian implies any relationship is linear in this sense.  It is easy enough to construct examples where $X$ and $Y$ each have a Gaussian distribution, where correlation is $0$ but there is strong strong non-linear dependence: such an example would not be "jointly" Gaussian.

Answer (score 0):

The [Pearson correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) does describe the linear correlation between two datasets. You got this one right. It is also a part of each and every covariance matrix, as $\rho_{xy}=\sigma_{xy}/{\sigma_{x}\sigma_{y}}$. There are some other kinds of correlation coefficients, such as [Spearman's rank correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient) and [Kendall's $\tau$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient).

> This means that *if there is no linear relationship, then there is no
> relationship*

Pardon my French, but this is totally wrong. variables can be dependent, can even be a function of each other - but with no correlation. Does this mean there is no relationship?

Consider the following variables: Let $\theta\sim U(0,2\pi)$ and denote the RVs $X=sin(\theta), Y=cos(\theta)$. The correlation coefficient is 0 (really easy to prove, try it!), but does that mean they are not related? Recalling the Pythagorean trigonometric identity $sin^2(\theta)+cos^2(\theta)=1$, we can formulate $X$ as a function of $Y$: $X=\pm\sqrt{1-Y^2}$. Clearly, $X,Y$ are dependent. The only meaning of zero correlation is that we cannot describe on of the as a linear function of the other, i.e there are no $a,b$ for which $X=aY+b$ for all values of $\theta$. That's it.

Comment: The "no relationship" line seems to mean for a distribution that is bivariate Gaussian. In such a distribution, zero correlation is equivalent to independent marginal distributions.